# Using scapy to send TCP handshake, but in wireshark the seq number is wrong?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, wireshark, scapy

For example, there are 2 hosts, A and B, whose IP addresses are 192.168.10.132 and 192.168.10.138 respectively. Host A sends a TCP packet with seq=1, and B replies with a packet with ack=1 and seq=2, and so on.

The code is as follow:

```
send(IP(dst='192.168.10.138', src='192.168.10.132')/TCP(sport=54321, dport=32145, seq=1, flags='S')) # Host A

send(IP(dst='192.168.10.132', src='192.168.10.138')/TCP(sport=32145, dport=54321, seq=2, ack=1, flags='SA')) # Host B
```

But in wireshark, the first packet captured shows seq=0?

[screenshot of wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7jf3.png)

Why does this situation  happen? Or what is the problem of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a feature, as explained in [*Wireshark*'s wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Relative_Sequence_Numbers):

> By default *Wireshark* and *TShark* will keep track of all *TCP* sessions and convert all *Sequence Numbers* (*SEQ* numbers) and *Acknowledge Numbers* (*ACK* numbers) into relative numbers. This means that instead of displaying the real/absolute *SEQ* and *ACK* numbers in the display, *Wireshark* will display a *SEQ* and *ACK* number relative to the first seen segment for that conversation.
>
> This means that all *SEQ* and *ACK* numbers always start at 0 for the first packet seen in each conversation.
>
> This makes the numbers much smaller and easier to read and compare than the real numbers which normally are initialized to randomly selected numbers in the range `0 - (2^32)-1` during the *SYN* phase.

If you're  interested in the real value of the *SEQ* number field for a certain packet, you can highlight that field in the *Packet Details* pane and view its value in the *Packet Bytes* pane.

Alternatively, the wiki suggests how the feature can be disabled altogether:

> Using relative sequence numbers is a usability enhancement, making the numbers easier to read and compare. In order to compare a dissection with data from a less advanced analyzer that can not handle relative sequence numbers it might be required to temporarily disable this feature in *Wireshark*.
>
> For *Wireshark* versions prior to 1.5: When the *Relative Sequence Numbers* preference is enabled *Wireshark* will also enable *"Window Scaling"*.
>
> For *Wireshark* 1.5 & newer: *"Window Scaling"* is a separate *TCP* preference enabled by default.
>
> If *"Window Scaling"* is enabled, *Wireshark* will try to monitor the *TCP Window Scaling* option negotiated during the *SYN* phase and if such *TCP Window Scaling* has been detected, *Wireshark* will also scale the window field and translate it to the effective window size. This may affect what the dissected and reported window is and may make *Wireshark* to decode packets differently, but more accurately, than other tools.
>
> To disable relative sequence numbers and instead display them as the real absolute numbers, go to the *TCP* preferences and untick the box for relative sequence numbers.

[image: TCP relative sequence numbers and window scaling]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That successfully solved my problem!